# AWS Reckognition Too many Rows in manifest Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rekognition

I'm getting "manifest_has_too_many_rows" error when trying to create a dataset from Amazon S3 in AWS Rekognition.

I am trying to create a dataset on Amazon reckognition for a project I'm working on

Comment: Any code please?

Comment: Please show us the manifest, or dataset, or code, or everything. You can edit your question to add these details. For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: That is the main issue i am using S3 to import dataset so there is no manifest file. But after experimenting i have noticed that if I try to add more than 7 folders (in my case each folder consists of 1000 images each) it gives me this error. But I want to create a dataset of over 20 folders each containing 1000 images.